# Rotate circular text

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, decorations

I am trying to approximate the following logo. 
[image]
This is necessary because we might do some corrections to the text, and especially the colors, so it is not desirable to keep going back into an image editor to fix these issues.

This question focuses solely on the text around the centered image. After some fiddling I used the image above to create the logo in the middle, and added some rotated text.

[image]

However I have two small problems

- How can I rotate the text "UiT" at the bottom, and make sure it is centered vertically?
- How can i replace the asterisk's * with bullets? I tried `\textbullet` and `$\bullet$`, alas both of these timed out my document.
- As always any other improvements or suggestions for the code is more than welcome.

## Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,  latexsym, amscd, amsthm}

% Commented out fonts to allow for compilation across tex distributions
% \usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}         % altermundus.com/pages/tkz/tikzrput/
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text}  % altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/ 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [circle, minimum width = 4.8cm,
    path picture = {
      \node [] at (path picture bounding box.center) {
        \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{UiT_Segl_Bok_Sort_960px.png}};
    }] {};
\path 
    [rotate=240,postaction={decoration={text along path,text={|\huge\bfseries|\ NORGES ARKTISKE UNIVERSITET * UiT *},
      text align=fit to path,reverse path}, decorate}]
     circle[radius=2.7cm] ; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is not compileable, it produces this error with MikTeX: `! LaTeX Error: Unknown option osfigures for package opensans`.

Comment: Ah, give me a few minutes to look at it. I only tried my code in overleaf where it compiles just fine. Hmf, it compiles just fine in TexLive. Does it compile for you without the `osfigures` option?

Comment: The option is imho now called oldstyle. And the document doesn't compile as we don't have the graphic.

Comment: The image is the first image in my post. Is there a way to make this clearer? Sorry, English is not my first language. Feel free to edit the post as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following code I was able to address my two points

```
\path 
    [rotate=240,postaction={decoration={text along path,text={|\huge\bfseries|\ NORGES ARKTISKE UNIVERSITET {\Large\textbullet} {\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{T}}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{I}}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{U}} {\Large\textbullet}},
      text align=fit to path,reverse path}, decorate}]
     circle[radius=2.7cm] ;
```

- To insert the `\textbullet` I needed to insert braces so that the option `\huge\bfseries` would not apply.
- To rotate the text I used `{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{U}}` again with the braces.

[image]